# Avoiding adding a new line at the end of file

Tags: c, printf, getchar

Given the code reading from the standard input

```
    int main() {
         int c;
         while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
              fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
         }
    }
```

This code is fine for reading all contents from the `stdin` containing multiple lines. But it will add a new line at the end of file. How can I modify the above code so that I can prevent from adding an extra new line `\n` in the last line of `stdin`? The example of `stdin` is given below.

```
hello world!!!
how is going today?
this is the last line in stdin
```

Comment: This doesn't add an *extra* newline, it just keeps the one that was already there.  Usually it's desirable to have every line, including the last one, end in a `\n` character.  Are you really sure you don't want it?

Comment: Where is the echo in your example?, using your code all lines are duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NateEldredge said in a friendly way, removing the trailing `'\n'` from the last line is dumb. By convention, on UNIX-like systems, every line in a textfile must be terminated with `'\n'`. But if you actually want to remove the last newline, maybe to be compatible with some lesser OS, you have to delay printing of characters until you know if the next read returned `EOF`, or not:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int c = getchar();
  int peek_c;
  if (c != EOF)
    {
      /* Print out everything except the last char */
      while ((peek_c = getchar()) != EOF)
        {
          fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
          c = peek_c; 
        }
      /* If the last char was not '\n', we print it
         (We only want to strip the last char if it is a newline)  */
      if (c != '\n')
         fprintf(stdout, "%c", c);
    } 
}
```